# Backbone Modal with Q.promise issue

Tags: backbone.js, modal-dialog, promise, q

We have a method (`onOpenNotitiesClicked`) for showing a Modal view for entering notes. We have implemented the Backbone Modal plugin for this (https://github.com/awkward/backbone.modal).

There are two situations:

1. There are not yet notes in the backend: initialize and render the
   modal
2. There are already notes in the backend => first collect them and
   then pass the notes to the modal (initialize) and then render

In the first situation it works fine! The modal is shown.
In the second situation, the modal is not shown. 
I have debugged both situations and in both situations, alle methods are executed and in the elements, I see the HTML of the modal view.

[image]

I suspect `this` looses some data during the Q/promise data get, but I can't see what/where/how/why....

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong? Or what I am missing?

The creation of the modal:

```
    onOpenNotitieClicked: function (event) {
        var $element, taak, taakId, id, options = {};

        $element = this.$(event.currentTarget).closest("li");
        id = $element.data("id");
        taakId = $element.data("taak-id");
        taak = this.getCurrentTask(event);

        options.taakKey = id;
        options.taakId = taakId;
        options.heeftNotities = taak.heeftNotities;
        options.datacontroller = this.datacontroller;
        this.notitiesOptions = options;
        // this.renderNotitieModal(options);
        if (taak.heeftNotities) {
            this.getActiviteitNotities(taakId).then(_.bind(this.onSuccessGetNotities, this), _.bind(this.onErrorGetNotities, this));
        } else {
            this.renderNotitieModal(this.notitiesOptions);
        }

    },
```

In case there are notes to be collected:

```
    getActiviteitNotities: function (taakId) {
        return this.datacontroller.getNotities(taakId);
    },

    onSuccessGetNotities: function (notities) {
        this.notitiesOptions.notities = notities;
        this.renderNotitieModal(this.notitiesOptions);
    },

    onErrorGetNotities: function () {
        this.renderNotitieModal(this.notitiesOptions);
    },
```

To get the notes from the backend, Q/promises is used.

```
    getNotities: function (taakId, refresh, klantorderId) {
        return Q.promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {};

            if (!this.notitiesCollection || this.taakId !== taakId || refresh) {
                delete this.notitiesCollection;

                this.notitiesCollection = this.createCollection("NotitiesCollection", {
                    id: this.taakId,
                    resource: this.NOTITIES_RESOURCE
                });

                if (taakId) {
                    this.taakId = taakId;

                    options = {
                        data: {
                            parentId: this.taakId
                        }
                    };
                } else if (klantorderId) {

                    options = {
                        data: {
                            klantorderId: klantorderId
                        }
                    };
                }

                resolve(this.notitiesCollection.fetch(options));
            } else if (this.notitiesCollection) {
                resolve(this.notitiesCollection.toJSON());
            } else {
                reject("ERROR");
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
```

Notities.js (the modal view):

```
(function () {
"use strict";

App.Bewaking.modals.BewakingNotitieModal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
    template: JST.bewaking_notitie_modal, //jshint ignore:line
    title: "Notities",
    formatter: new App.Main.helpers.Formatter(),

    events: {
        "click #save-notitie": "onSaveNotitieClicked"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.taakId = options.taakId;
        this.taakKey = options.taakKey;
        this.datacontroller = options.datacontroller;
        this.notities = options.notities;
    },

    afterRender: function () {
        console.log("afterRender");
        this.$notitieModal = this.$("#notitieModal");
        this.$nieuweNotitie = this.$("#nieuwe-notitie");
        this.$notitieErrorTekst = this.$("#notitie-error-tekst");

        this.$notitieModal.on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
            this.$nieuweNotitie.focus();
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.notities);
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            formatter: this.formatter,
            notities: this.notities
        }));

        return this;
    }
 });
}());
```